# ACL permission defaults are not applying to new files

Tags: 14.04, command-line, server, permissions, acl

I am trying to set up ACL's so that all new sub-directories and files withing a directory automatically inherit it's parents permissions. From what I understand I could achieve this by setting the default permissions for all groups and users, this is what I did:

```
mkdir test 
chown root:media test
chmod 775 test
chmod g+s test (so all directories and files are in the same group)
setfacl -dm g::rwx test
getfacl test
```

Here is the output of the last command:

```
# file: test
# owner: dom
# group: media
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x 
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

All seems correct but when I create files withing thest directory they do not have correct permissions.

```
cd test
mkdir dir
touch file
ls -l
```

Here are the results of the last command:

```
root@Server:/test# ls -l
total 4 
drwxrwsr-x+ 2 root media 4096 Oct 27 19:24 dir
-rw-rw-r--  1 root media    0 Oct 27 19:24 file
```

I am using Ubuntu Server 14.04 with on ext4 file system.

Ac you can see the directory has the correct permissions but the file is missing execute permissions. I have also tried this on another directory (/mnt/disk1) and the file was missing read permissions also. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs) says a three-year-old bug makes ACLs ineffective. Could that be your issue?

Comment: @muru that's unbelievable. Does it mean you simply cannot have ACL defaults in linux no matter what?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know much about ACLs, but that notice is present very prominently in the wiki page, so I figured it might be what you are facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With no other answer I am adding my answer since the issue has been somewhat resolved.

Due to a three year old (!) [cp/mv in coreutils don't respect the default ACL of parent directories bug](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=8527) the default ACL permission are non-functional and the reason acl's did not work for me.

Comment: How has this issue been resolved? Is there a [launchpad bug](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acl/+bugs) for this issue?

Comment: The question is resolved but not the bug, the solution is simply not to use ACL as it is broken and since it broken for 3+ years there's no reason to believe it will be fixed soon.

Comment: What is the solution if we want this behaviour though? What else can we use?